# Coefficients of linear combination of matrices

Tags: python, math, optimization, scipy, linear-algebra

We have four matrices A, B, C, D of the same dimension (m * n * p). We need to find coefficients x1, x2, x3 such that we:

```
minimize (D - x1 * A - x2 * B - x3 * C)**2
```

given that `x1 + x2 + x3 = 1` and

```
0<= x1,x2,x3 <=1
```

Is there any efficient way to minimize the sum of squares of this in Python?

Comment: @Reinderien,  it's just a convex combination of the matrices

Comment: @Reinderien yes my aim is to get x1 * A - x2 * B - x3 * C as close to D as possible, where x's are scalars and A,B,C are matrices.

Comment: It seems plausible to me that this problem has a solution expressible via linear algebra. The objective function is a quadratic form, and the constraint is a plane, so the objective constrained to the plane is again a quadratic form in some new basis. I'll bet if you take it up on math.stackexchange.com someone can help you work out the details. An exact solution like that has a couple of things going for it -- one is that it can help you get insight about the problem and solution, the other is the exact solution may be computable without resorting to numerical methods. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: If this is a homework problem, then you might find it has a straight forward-ish solution. If you ignore the inequality for a moment, then you have an equation of the form alpha*x1^2 + beta*x1*x2 + gamma*x2^2 + delta = 0. If you take partial derivatives to find the stationary points you might find the global minimum that way. Depeding on the values in the matrices, the equation could be divergent though, or have a global minimum that doesn't satisfy the inequalities. In that case, it's back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 3):

If you want true sum-of-squares minimization, that's possible in Scipy with a linear constraint:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
D = rand.random(size=(5, 7, 6))
ABC = rand.random(size=(3, *D.shape))


def objective(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    delta = (
        D - x[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * ABC
    ).ravel()
    return delta.dot(delta)


result = minimize(
    fun=objective,
    x0=[1/3, 1/3, 1/3],
    bounds=[[0,1], [0,1], [0,1]],
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=[1, 1, 1], lb=1, ub=1),
)
print(result)
```

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: 146.34193150290096
       x: [ 3.660e-01  3.163e-01  3.177e-01]
     nit: 4
     jac: [-6.803e+01 -6.803e+01 -6.803e+01]
    nfev: 20
    njev: 4
```

An alternative that turns out not to be faster, and will not have the same numerical characteristics, is if you change this to a min-of-absolute error and use linear programming instead:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import linprog

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
m, n, p, q = 5, 7, 6, 3
mnp = m*n*p
D = rand.random(size=(m, n, p))
ABC = rand.random(size=(m, n, p, q))

# x, and objective auxiliaries for each element of D
c = np.ones(shape=q + mnp)
c[:q] = 0  # x is not minimized, objectives are

bounds = np.zeros((q + mnp, 2))
bounds[:q, 1] = 1        # 0 <= x <= 1
bounds[q:, 1] = np.inf   # 0 <= o

A_eq = np.zeros((1, q + mnp))
A_eq[0, :q] = 1  # sum(x) == 1

# For each element of D and its corresponding objective o:
# -D + x.abc <= o     A  B  C -1 0 0 0 0 ... <=  D
#  D - x.abc <= o    -A -B -C -1 0 0 0 0 ... <= -D
A_ub = np.block([
    [+ABC.reshape((-1, q)), -np.eye(mnp)],
    [-ABC.reshape((-1, q)), -np.eye(mnp)],
])
b_ub = np.concatenate((+D.ravel(), -D.ravel()))

result = linprog(
    c=c, bounds=bounds,
    A_eq=A_eq, b_eq=[1],
    A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub)
x = result.x[:q]
obj = result.x[q:]
print(result)
print('x =', x)

# Verification
assert result.success
assert np.isclose(1, x.sum())
assert np.all(0 <= x)
assert np.all(x <= 1)

delta = np.abs(
    D - (
        x[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]*ABC
    ).sum(axis=-1)
).ravel()
assert np.allclose(delta, obj)
```

```
        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: 58.41554582615268
              x: [ 1.614e-01  5.168e-01 ...  6.642e-02  3.075e-01]
            nit: 212
          lower:  residual: [ 1.614e-01  5.168e-01 ...  6.642e-02
                              3.075e-01]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
          upper:  residual: [ 8.386e-01  4.832e-01 ...        inf
                                    inf]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
          eqlin:  residual: [ 0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 1.100e+00]
        ineqlin:  residual: [ 7.751e-01  0.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [-0.000e+00 -1.000e+00 ... -1.000e+00
                             -1.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 0
 mip_dual_bound: 0.0
        mip_gap: 0.0
x = [0.16136498 0.51681836 0.32181666]
```

The linear program runs for me in 15 ms, compared to  1.5 ms for the generic minimization.

You ask:

> if we change it to min-of-absolute error & use linear programming what kind of characteristics would be different?

See e.g. [Why does regression use least "squares" instead of least "absolute values"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580109) . The trade-offs are non-trivial.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible that you could point me to some tutorial or some documentation related to the solution that I could read up for the algorithm you have mentioned? Also, if we change it to min-of-absolute error & use linear programming what kind of characteristics would be different? Can you point me to some doc related to the linear programming approach as well? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Just one hint: You could use [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html) to build the matrix A_ub and the vector b_ub instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: @joni great suggestion! `block` for the matrix, `concatenate` for the vector.